# Why redux-observeable instead of just rxjs with store.dispatch?

Tags: redux-observable

I don't understand why I need to use redux-observable? Can't I just create my own middleware to listen and emit to a subject on actions to redux. And then create pipelines (in place of epics) that use `store.dispatch()` and `store.getState()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can write your own Redux-Observable style middleware.

Someone else I know has to do that because her company hasn't adopted RxJS, but then she loses out on a lot of the tooling you get from both Redux and RxJS pipeline operators.

Doing it yourself isn't always the best way though. Redux-Observable handles a lot of tough pieces behind the scenes. I've written my own for specific scenarios where I don't have Redux, but if I do, I go with Redux-Observable.

A different way to describe it, you could create a middleware function for every epic, or you could create a single middleware that puts together a bunch of epics and creates a single parent pipeline.

In the same way, you could have a single reducer that combines a bunch of smaller reducers together. `combineReducers` lets you do this in a hierarchy, but each reducer doesn't know about the state of the others.

`combineEpics` does this same thing. While you can add them hierarchically, technically that doesn't matter. To be clear, hierarchy does matter if you pipe off `combineEpics` anywhere in your codebase. Probably not advised.

Your question could also be rephrased to "why should I use Redux if I could write my own object with `getState`, `dispatch`, and `subscribe` methods? The only reason you'd write your own Redux is if you're in a situation where you don't want to use reducers for state management or have a custom scenario where you want Redux-like behavior, but not actually Redux the library.